# React-bootstrap not loaded, but imported?

Tags: reactjs

I am importing {Button, ButtonToolbar} from 'react-bootstrap' (it's saved in the dependencies list), however my page still appears bare. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Thanks for all the downvotes. Someone care to answer my question?

Comment: what's the error you are seeing in console?

Comment: No error in the console.

Comment: can you please add relevant code to this post?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include stylessheet of bootstrap in your index.html? react-bootstrap still needs this to work properly. Hope it helps

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

However, I think you should just use normal button bootstrap by adding className of btn btn-primary, it still works fine with reactjs and give you ability to customize

Comment: I normally use react-bootstrap for component like Modal in my reactjs project since you can't do it with normal bootstrap by adding class name